# Question about Bounties and editing your question.

Tags: support, bounty

Is it possible to have multiple active bounites? I either can't seem to remember how to offer a bounty (although I just did a few days ago), or the site won't allow me to have multiple active bounties... Which one is it?

Also, everytime I edit a question it reappears on the front page of S.E., I could imagine that this annoys some people (and it certainly makes me feel a little uneasy). How can I edit my question and not have it reappear on the top of the list of questions?

Comment: On the subject of bounties, see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/16067#16067). On editing, nope, no way to make edits non-disruptive; this is intentional so that any vandalism is easily acted upon when seen.

Comment: Ok, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one active bounty at any given time.

Editing is intended to bump questions, just like answers, so changes are more visible to others.